# Weird Geometry I Can't Even Select

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm getting weird geometry i don't think i ever even created (I've been sleepwalking lately tho and sometimes bad things have happened to my projects over night...)

anyway this stuff just appeared a day or so ago.  I can't even select it in object or in edit mode, and nothing is "unselectable" in the outliner, afaik...  I would try the L or ctrl L thing but i cant grab any vertices.

anyone able to help?
Thank you all!

[image: wtf]

Comment: Can you please show screenshots and not photos? And possibly cropped to what is "unselectable". It's barely anything visible especially on the second one

Comment: Those look like artifacts created by modifiers, check your modifier stack and check for duplicate or overlapping geometry

Comment: Duarte was right.   Thank you . Sorry bout the pics... ctrl F3 huh? Nifty!

Comment: Could you please post what you found as an answer below please? It may be useful for future users with similar problems. Add a small description of what was wrong, how you found out and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Solved by Duarte... Thank you!

It was a solidify modifier.  The glossy geometry seems to be the solidify being pushed out of a subdivision in the middle of the rectagular cubes.  The other piece of "mysterious" uninvited geometry just behind the silver, vertical cylinders was a plane in the now joined object...  [image]
[image: Solidify Removed and in Wireframe]